# A function $f$ such that $\lim_{x\to b}f(x)=+\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to b}f'(x)=-\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

Is there any continuously differentiable function $f:[a,b)\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $$\lim_{x\to b}f(x)=+\infty$$ and
$$\lim_{x\to b}f'(x)=-\infty$$
?

Comment: I'd say no since $x=b$ is a vertical asymptote of $f$ tending to positive infinity, which implies $f$ is concave up on some interval $(c,b), c\in(a,b)$, but $f$ has to be concave down for $(b-\epsilon,b)$ and some specific $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: However, you can have $\lim \inf f' = - \infty$ and $\lim f = + \infty$.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122  yeah, maybe something like $f(x)=\frac{1}{x} |\cos(\frac{1}{x})|$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. If $$\lim_{x\rightarrow b}f(x)=\infty$$ then there exists an increasing sequence $x_n$ such that $f(x_n)$ increases to $\infty$. Applying the Mean Value Theorem at each $x_n$ and $x_{n+1}$, you get $y_n \in (x_n,x_{n+1})$ such that $f^{'}(y_n)>0$. So $$\lim_{x \rightarrow b}f^{'}(x)\neq -\infty$$